# Hashkey in certificates for downloadable fonts?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-fonts, android-downloadable-fonts

Currently, I am using Downloadable Fonts in my project. Reference link: [Downloadable Font](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#via-android-studio).

It generates certification file with two hash (dev and Prod) as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
        <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev</item>
        <item>@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod</item>
    </array>
    <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_dev">
        <item>
           [HASH]
        </item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs_prod">
        <item>
            [HASH]
        </item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

My concerns are:

1) How are both hash keys generated? are they using keystore to generate hash key?

2) Can we change the hash key for Prod? Will it work after publishing an application to play store (after creating signed apk)?